# Lucene.net Spatial Circle boundingbox

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I am using Lucene.net spatial lib to search points inside a circle radius.
I'm using SpatialContext not geographic and PointVectorStrategy.

From what I see in the source code and in my tests, Lucene.net when getting the circle's bounding box, it returns the square where the circle fits in, making it possible for my query to return points that are outside the circle but inside the square (in the corners).

Is there a way to change it to search only inside the circle?

```
private readonly SpatialContext _ctx;
private readonly PointVectorStrategy _strategy;

_ctx = new SpatialContext(false);
_strategy = new PointVectorStrategy(_ctx, "location");

var args = new SpatialArgs(SpatialOperation.IsWithin, _ctx.MakeCircle(criteria.X, criteria.Y, criteria.Radius));
var spatialquery = _strategy.MakeQuery(args);
```